# Filtering Query Results to keep certain Template but when that template doesn't exist still have an entry

Tags: sql

I have 3 Tables A,B,C Which I wish to join together, removing duplicate values from a field in A but giving preference to a certain value in C.

My Tables are as follows.

A

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Installation | Substructure | Description     |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| A            | 12           | non-unique text |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| A            | 22           | Non-unique text |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| B            | 54           | Non-unique text |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

This if Left Joined with table B on the Substructure

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Substructure | Reference |
+--------------+-----------+
| 12           | REF001    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 12           | REF002    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 12           | REF003    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 22           | REF004    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 22           | REF005    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 54           | REF006    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 54           | REF007    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 54           | REF008    |
+--------------+-----------+
```

This is further Right joined with Table C on the Reference

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| Reference | Description     | Template_Type |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| REF001    | Some Text       | PNID          |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| REF002    | More Text       | ISO           |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| REF003    | Non-Unique Text | Phot          |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
```

The current form of the code is something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Substructure,
    A.Description,
    B.Reference,
    C.Description AS REF_DES
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON (A.SUBSTRUCTURE = B.SUBSTRUCTURE)
RIGHT JOIN C ON (B.REFERENCE = C.REFERENCE)
```

Which works and returns every Template_Type , Reference associated with a given Substructure. However what I'd like to do now is remove the duplicate substructure entries from the returned query, keeping those that have the Template Type as PNID but if that substructure does not have an entry with a PNID I'd still like to have an entry for that substructure returned. If there's no document entry at all then I'd also like an entry for that sub-structure returned.

I tried using various WHERE conditions to filter the results further but obviously filtering on TEMPLATE_TYPE = value will exclude all the substructures that do not have PNIDS.

Unfortunately I have no control over how the data is stored in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to run a sub-query filtering Table C for PNIDs and then joining against the query results.